# On measuring the common mode gain of an op-amp using a simulator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, multisim, common-mode, orcad

I have been trying for a while now to measure the common voltage gain of the LM741, which according to *Op Amps: Design, Application, and Troubleshooting* page 21 is around 6, using Multsim and Orcad. The images bellow are from the same reference.

[image]

[image]

So, in theory, if I realize the circuit above, and set the common input voltage to some value, I should get around 6 times this value at the output. Using Orcad with 1 mV at the input:[image]

I get around 4 V at the output:
[image]

Whereas with Multism, for the same values as in Orcad, I get 14 volts at the output, which I believe means the amp is saturated.

[image]

[image]

Why are all these values so inconsistent with each other? And is it even possible to measure the common gain using a simulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impractical to directly measure the CMRR or common mode open-loop gain with a real op-amp, so if you do chance to measure it that indicates the model is not very realistic. For example the [typical](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf) open-loop gain is 200,000 (but it might be as low as 25,000). The typical offset voltage is 1mV (but it might be as much as 6mV). At +/-1mV, the open-loop output voltage will typically be saturated with inputs shorted together. If the op-amp model has zero offset voltage, that's not very realistic. +/-75uV is more than enough to typically saturate an op-amp with +/-15V supplies and gain of 200,000.

Secondly, you should be looking at the **change** in output voltage with **change** in common mode voltage. In your first example, you are getting very little change. BUT your numbers will be bogus anyway, since the open loop gain of a 741 is much lower than 200,000 typically at a high frequency like 200Hz.

You can continue along this path by nulling the offset voltage to bring the output well within the output range then change the DC common mode voltage and find the DC operating point. If the gain is of the order of 6 you'd not want to change it too much.

A better approach for measuring CMRR is described in [this](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-042.pdf) application note. There are analogous indirect methods of inferring open-loop gain from a closed-loop circuit.

[image]